# Getting data from a linked CakePHP3 entity

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a `User` entity with a `hasMany` relationship to `Profile` via  a `user_id` foreign key.

Within my `User` class I'm trying to create a virtual field so I can access the `name` property of the linked `Profile` entity

```
protected $_virtual = ['profile_name'];
protected function _getProfileName() 
{
    return $this->profile->name;
}
```

Whatever I try I get `Trying to get property of non-object`

I've also tried:

```
$this->_properties['profile']->name;
$this->profile->_properties['name'];
```

I know I can get this data by building a query up using `Cake\ORM\Table` but I has hoping to aovid that.

What am I doing wrong?

p.s. there is definitely linked data between the two tables.

Comment: The relationship is between your tables/table classes, not your entities, entities are dumb data containers, they don't know (or shouldn't know) anything about relations, people might misunderstand you when you're talking about entities in that context. That being said, the first step when being confrontend with that error, should be to debug what the referenced property actually _is/holds_, when it's not an object (which would actually be wrong if it where btw). Such debugging details should always be included in your questions, often problems solve themselves when gathering such information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be

> That's not how it works

Instead, use 'eager loading' to get the linked entity data. That is to say use the `contain` method when using `find()`:

e.g.

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('users');
$query = $users->find('all', ['contain' => ["Profiles"]])
                ->where(['id' => $userId])
                ->first();
```

or on the query object itself:

```
$query->contain(['Profiles']);
```

In this example `$query` will contain Profile entity objects along with the User entity

i.e. `$query->profiles` is an array of Profile entities